# How to call Dag from a python Script

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am new to Airflow, I want to know if i can execute a python script which calls airflow dag. For example 
I want to execute /home/ec2-user/rundag.py script.
runday.py contains below two lines
import os
os.system('python /home/ec2-user/airflow/dags/testsftp.py')

I tried running but testsftp job didn't kicked off. Let me know if i did anything wrong or is it possible to call a dag as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the [experimental REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/api.html).

By default the experimental API is unsecured, and hence before continuing you should define an `auth_backend` in the `airflow.cfg` in order to secure it.

Once the REST API is set up, you could hit this endpoint:
`http://{HOST}:{PORT}/admin/rest_api/api/v1.0/trigger_dag?dag_id={dag_id}&run_id={run_id}&conf={url_encoded_json_parameters}`

Replacing dag_id with the id of your dag, either omitting run_id or specify a unique id, and passing a url encoded json for conf (with any of the parameters you need in the triggered dag).